# Responsive Skrollr with constants

Tags: jquery, html, skrollr

I'm a bit confused trying to make Skrollr responsive by using data constants — I'm unsure of what to do with the constant value... If my window height is returned in the constant (e.g.: 1024px), how do I tell my elements to use this value to control animations?

Here's my code:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var s = skrollr.init({
        beforerender: function(data) {
            return data.direction == 'down';
        },
        render: function(data) {
            console.log(data.curTop);
        },
        forceHeight: false,
        constants: {
            screen: function() {
                return $(window).height();
            }
        }
    });
};
$(function() {
    skrollr.get().refresh();
});
```

Thanks for any insight into this issue.

Comment: Hi, could you show the HTML you are using as well?

Comment: Sure.  `<blockquote class="vertical-center" data-_screen-0="@Animate: 0;" data-_screen-150p="@Animate: 0;" data-_screen-200p="@Animate: 1;" data-_screen-250p="@Animate: 1;">
            <p>...</p>
        </blockquote>`

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding it seems you have everything set up the way it should be. `data-_screen-0="@Animate: 0;"` is interpreted as `data-(the window height minus 0p)` Btw, are you intending to use 'p' unit values rather than px or pt? I haven't seen that unit value used before. Also, I believe I once ran into an issue when not specifying the unit even on a 0 value. **edit**: oh, p is interpreted as a percentage unit, nevermind.

Comment: Thanks. Above was an example of my setup but the problem is that i have several dynamic elements that i need to animate in a responsive environment and i'm unsure of the best way to utilize the constant as a linchpin for all of these elements. If elements are fed the "screen" value, which reflects the window height, then how do I code the dynamic elements to respond correctly on whatever screen using this value?

Comment: I _think_ I get it. But it seems to me you might be going about achieving a desired effect in a complex manner and there might be an easier way to reach the same end result. I created [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/damo_s/7uthprmu/) based on your code but naturally I didn't get very far without knowing more about your setup and what effect you're trying to achieve. That said, the fiddle I linked above is responsive as I understand the term. Resize the browser up and down and the skrollable element stays centered. You might of course be trying to achieve something completely different.

Comment: Sure, but the issue is that if all elements down the page use these data attributes they will all fire at the same time -- in your example, after scrolling the page the full height of the screen, plus 50% of that screen's height, elements will animate. With dynamic elements, I cannot know precisely when each will appear on the screen (e.g.: `data-_screen-250%`, `data-_screen-1200%`)... I need the elements to animate based on their position on the screen, using the constant; not based on the amount scrolled down. Does this make sense? Thanks again.